# Unit Testing: Passing a value within a method

Tags: unit-test

I have a method like this (this is partial but the rest of it is less important to the question).

```
public static List<Contact> syncList() {
        List<Contact> syncList = new List<Contact>();
        Map<Id, List<Contact>> lookerByIds = zuoraContactSync.lookerById(zuoraContactSync.mergeList());
        List<Contact> sfdcList = [SELECT AccountId, Email, FirstName, LastName, status__c FROM Contact WHERE ID in : lookerByIds.keySet()];
        //set status__c AKA Role to Billing Contact
        system.debug(sfdcList.size());

        for(Contact con : sfdcList) { 
{

//other code

return syncList;
```

My problem is that I do not know how to pass a value to the lookerByIds map. This is a method calling out to an external location. To test that particular method I just built a list and passed it to the method.

So my question is, how do I alter this? Do I make syncList() take an argument like:

`syncList(Map<Id, List<Contact>> mapItems)`? If so, how do I artificially populate something like that? It is pretty important that I keep this particular method a void as this is going into a schedulable.

Comment: what inputs does `zuoraContactSync.mergeList()` take? that is what you need to establish in the testmethod before testing `syncList()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd solve this by having a field on the object which the Test method sets. This function can then check to see if that field is set, and uses it, instead of calling out.

```java
public static List<Contact> syncList() {
    List<Contact> syncList = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id, List<Contact>> lookerByIds;
    if (debugfield != null) {
        lookerByIds = debugfield;
    } else {
        lookerByIds = zuoraContactSync.lookerById(zuoraContactSync.mergeList());
    }
    ...
```

A better way would be to strucutre the code to make testing easier. There are whole books on this subject, I'm sure :-)